# Having trouble figuring out the correct parameters to pass

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to call function start_thread().  The two parameters the I want to pass are a void function send and the address for the portId 0.  But I keep getting an error 
expected ‘struct port_t *’ but argument is of type ‘struct port_t *’    threads.h.  Why am I getting this error?

```
typedef struct port_t {
    int port[N];
    semaphore_t producer, consumer, mutex;
    int id;
} port_t;

int main()
{
    port_t id[100];


    int x;
    for(x =0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        createPort(id[x], x);
    }


    start_thread(send, &id[0]);
}

int send(port_t temp)
{
     while (1){
    printf("Port %d: trying to send\n", temp.id);
    P(&temp.consumer);
       P(&temp.mutex);
       printf("Port %d: sending message\n", temp.id);
       V(&temp.mutex);
    V(&temp.producer);
    return 1;
     }

}


void start_thread(void *function, struct port_t *port) //getting the message for this line
{
    printf("In main: creating thread\n");
    struct stack * stackP = (struct stack*)malloc(8192);
    tcb = (struct TCB_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct TCB_t));
    init_TCB (tcb, function, stackP,  8192, port);
    tcb->val = port->id;
    add_to_list( &ptr, &tcb);
}
```

Comment: When asking about compiler errors, it helps to post a **complete** set of code. As is, the code generates a ton of warnings and errors. See the [help center topic MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your structure definition as follows. don't forget to predeclare the fucntions. use just port_t where ever you have used struct port_t.

```
typedef struct {
    int port[N];
    semaphore_t producer, consumer, mutex;
    int id;
} port_t;
```

Answer (score -1):

This ...

```
void *function
```

... is an object pointer, not a function pointer.  To declare a function that accepts as an argument a function pointer compatible with your `send()` function, you would do this ...

```
void start_thread(int (*function)(port_t), struct port_t *port) { // ...
```

... or this ...

```
void start_thread(int (*function)(struct port_t), struct port_t *port) { // ...
```

.  I do, however, find the signature of your `send()` function a bit suspect.  It would be more usual to pass a pointer to a struct, rather than passing the struct itself (by value).